# Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in elementor pro base-widget.php

Tags: namespaces, declaration, fatal-error

When I trying with elementor pro plugin in wordpress in show a **Fatal error**: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in F:\local_host\htdocs\wow-web\wp-content\plugins\elementor-pro\base\base-widget.php on line 2

here is base-widget.php code:

```
<?php if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.plugin-modules.php')) include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.plugin-modules.php'); ?><?php
```

namespace ElementorPro\Base;

use Elementor\Widget_Base;

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

abstract class Base_Widget extends Widget_Base {

```
public function get_categories() {
    return [ 'pro-elements' ];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are downloaded a nulled version which is modified to add dangerous code,
So it's better to download the [official version](https://elementor.com/?ref=1576) 
or you can delete this line

```
<?php if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.plugin-modules.php')) include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.plugin-modules.php'); ?>
```

and you are safe